# why request body is blank in node js + react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multipartform-data

I am sending post request with `FormData` .but when I checked on node server my `body` is `blanked` why ?
I do the following steps

```
 let formData = new FormData();
                // add one or more of your files in FormData
                // again, the original file is located at the `originFileObj` key
                formData.append("file", values['Temp_id_card'].fileList[0].originFileObj);
                formData.append("Emp No",values['Emp No'].toLowerCase())
                formData.append("Remarks",values['Remarks'])
                formData.append("UpdatedStatus",values['Status'])
                formData.append("id",id)
                formData.append("Att Date",attDate)
```

send data like that

```
export const sendPostRequest1 = (url, data, config = {}) => {
    let updatedConfig = {
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${getAuthToken()}` || ""},
        ...config
    };
    return axios.post(url, data, updatedConfig);
}
```

when i checked on `network` tap it shows data is send

[image]

but When debug on node server it shows empty body  why ?

Node js code

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        if(req.user.userId === req.body.userId){
            callback(null, "./Images");
        }else {
            throw new AuthenticationError("Unauthorized User");
        }

    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).array("file", 1); //Field name and max count
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.end("Something went wrong!");
        }
        return res.end("File uploaded successfully!.");
    });
});
```

when I checked on this `if(req.user.userId === req.body.userId){` line `req.body` is empty object ?

I also added this my middleware

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "100mb"}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb",extended: false }));
    app.use(requestLogger);
    app.use(helmet());
```

Comment: If is local host is ok ,but forremote service should change the url .another think var express = require('express');
var app = express(); .So app.post insted of router.post

Answer (score 0):

Fetched the same issue(Angular+NodeJs), and solved by the help of middleware.

Just write
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
instead of
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

[For more details](https://github.com/PraveenMistry/FilePublication-Angular-Node-Mysql/blob/master/routes/Files.js)